# Inserting Values into table with Date Data Type

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
create table order_information (

    donut_order_id smallint,
    order_date date,
    special_handling_notes varchar(255),

    primary key(donut_order_id)

);
```

My insert statement looks like this:

```
insert into order_information(donut_order_id, order_date, special_handling_notes), values(1, '2018-01-01', 'do not eat any of them on the way');
```

My error message looks like this:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ', values(1, '2018-01-01', 'do not eat any of them
>   on the way')' at line 1   0.000 sec

The documentation looks like this:

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Documentation is located [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the info provided in your question, there's a possibility that the other fields, not necessarily the order_date field, might be the cause of the error. Consider primary key (is there another record with value of 1?), or string format (not sure if single/double quotes matter), etc.

Comment: Nope, table is completely empty.

Comment: oh ok, primary key constraint violation would give another error anyway, now that i think about it. looks like you have your answer below though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put comma after `into ...`.

Correct insert: 
`insert into order_information(donut_order_id, order_date, special_handling_notes) values(1, '2018-01-01', 'do not eat any of them on the way');`

Comment: ah, such a simple mistake, how did I not catch that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, the MySql error is actually kind of misleading in my opinion as it only provided the context only after the actual syntax error. E.g. in PostgreSQL the error message looks like this: `ERROR: syntax error at or near ","` so I can see how you did not catch that.